# Operating Systems: deadlock possible if a process can only lock one mutex at a time?

Tags: system, mutex, deadlock

Is a deadlock possible in an operating system which disallows nested locking, so that a process can only lock one mutex at a time?

I think it wouldn't be possible, since for a process to acquire another lock it would need to release any lock it's holding. but I am not that familiar with deadlock situations. Is my logic correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends how you define lock, if you mean any activity with the potential to block then yes, it would be correct that the if a deadlock is not possible if only one lock can be taken at once. If you only mean explicitly created mutexes and semaphores deadlock is still possible as there are things other than taking a lock which can cause blocking.

However the only implementations I know of which did something like this were old operating systems which had only a single lock for all shared resources and effectively only allowed a single thread to be in kernel space at once. This causes exceedingly poor performance in multi core systems, it is better to use other techniques such as ordered lock acquisition and time-outs in a modern multi-core or multi-cpu system rather than revert to  this technique.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There would be explicitly created mutexes, but a process can not acquire another mutex lock unless it releases the one it is holding, if any, first. How would a deadlock be possible in this situation?

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying now, if a process was blocked via another method such as a signal, or the kernel changing the process state then it would still be holding the mutex, which could cause a deadlock. Correct?

Comment: @Kanchobi Exactly, there are a number of reasons a process may block other than trying to take a mutex, they may attempt to use a hardware peripheral which is implicitly blocking or the process could crash/hang indefinitely while holding it without releasing it. Unfortunately we cannot control all the sources of process blocking in a normal multi tasking system so must instead manage it appropriately.

Comment: @Kanchobi For an example (albeit an unusual one) see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455371/can-the-in-as-well-as-ins-insb-etc-instruction-block-in-x86-assembly for how a process can be blocked by simply running an instruction, let alone acquiring a lock.